# std::atomic support in g++ 4.4.3

Tags: c++11, g++, atomic

I am using g++ version 4.4.3 on Ubuntu OS. According to this matrix [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html) it is supposed to support also `std::atomic`. Each time I use

```
 #include <atomic>
```

the compiler gives me an error and says `error: atomic: No such file or directory`.

Have you experienced the same problem?
I am compiling using the following line

```
    g++ -std=c++0x -Wall myCode.cpp -o myApp</code>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `#include <cstdatomic>` instead.

Comment: Why don't they use the proper header name?

Comment: According to [N2427](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html) the proper header names are `cstdatomic` or `atomic.h`, not `atomic.`