# How to include <atomic> in C++ on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, pthreads, atomic

I am trying to include atomic in my C++ pthread program.

```
#include <atomic>
```

But, i got error:

error: atomic: No such file or directory

I tried :

```
 #include <asm/atomic>
 #include <atomic.h>
 #include <linux/atomic>
 #include <util/atomic>
 #include <stdcatomic>
 #include <catomic>
```

No one works.

My gcc is  gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)

The post :

[#include <cstdatomic> "no such file" in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697588/include-cstdatomic-no-such-file-in-ubuntu)

[std::atomic support in g++ 4.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620559/stdatomic-support-in-g-4-4-3)

do not work either.

```
And #include <thread> also got : No such file or directory
```

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks !

UPDATE,

I am trying to install GCC 4.7 on Linux, but in "make check", I got error,

```
   autogen -T /remote/mypath/gcc_4_7_2012_5_28/gcc_4_7_new_2012_5_29/trunk/fixincludes/check.tpl , remote/mypath/gcc_4_7_2012_5_28/gcc_4_7_new_2012_5_29/trunk/fixincludes/inclhack.def ,

   make[2]: execvp: autogen: Permission denied, then I tried to install autogen, but 
   got: I need to install guile-devel, then when I installed guile-2.0.5-2.1.src.rpm , 

   I got  rpm -ivh guile-2.0.5-2.1.src.rpm, warning: guile-2.0.5-2.1.src.rpm: Header V3 
   RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 3dbdc284

   error: cannot write to %sourcedir /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES, I cannot get root 
   authorization.
```

Any help will be appreciated. thanks !

Comment: Upgrade your GCC first, your version is quite old, it doesn't support `<atomic>`.

Comment: `atomic` was introduced in a newer version of C++ (C++11). Your g++ has been written before `atomic` was invented!

Comment: It seems you're running RHEL 5. This was released in 2007, making it *very* old - GCC 4.1.2 was released in February 2007 as well. You'll need to look at what your options for upgrading are, either your whole distribution or your GCC & standard library toolchain.

Comment: latest gcc is 4.7, what you have there is a bit rusty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your post is a little confusing, since you link to a post that says GCC 4.4 is required for `atomic`, yet you are expecting it to work on 4.1.x.

You'll need to upgrade to at least GCC 4.4 for `atomic` support. There is no way to enable support for atomic in GCC 4.1, though you can use [`boost::atomic`](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/doc/index.html) instead. For future reference, [this chart](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) shows which version of GCC supports which C++11 features.

If for some reason you can't upgrade GCC, you could also try using a different compiler altogether (e.g. clang).

Comment: Hi, I use gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC), but still got error: atomic: No such file or directory, thanks !

Comment: @user Did you remember to use `--std=c++11`?

Comment: yes, I have tried -std=c++0x and -std=c++11, my gcc only support -std=c++0x, none works, same error !

Comment: Note in the gcc 4.4 release notes that no `<atomic>` was delivered, a `<cstdatomic>` was though.

Answer (score 2):

[This table](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) keeps track of gcc implementation status. Your compiler version doesn't support atomics yet.

In any case you need to use the `std=c++11` (or `c++0x` in older versions) switch to enable C++11 features.

Comment: Hi, I use gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC), but still got error: atomic: No such file or directory, thanks !

Comment: I strongly suggest to update to the latest release of GCC, i.e. GCC **4.7**; you may perhaps even need to build it from source, if your distribution don't package such a recent version of GCC

Answer (score 1):

Indeed gcc 4.4 could not compile for me a code containing `#include <atomic>`.
This happened while compiling someone else's code ([fasttext](https://github.com/salestock/fastText.py/blob/master/fasttext/cpp/src/fasttext.h)), so I prefered to avoid changing the code to `#include <cstdatomic>`.

I upgraded to gcc 4.8 and it worked.

If you're using CentOS 6.8, [here is how to upgrade gcc](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos).